# Unable to Run Adhoc Apps After Purging Profile & Starting Fresh

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've been pulling my hair out over the past few hours, attempting to get a simple "Hello World" app running on my iOS device in adhoc mode:

- Assuming I had screwed something up, I decided to follow the steps on Apple's "[How do I delete/revoke my certificates and start over fresh](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG15)."  I also followed the steps in "[Keep Your Profile Library Clean](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG15)."
- Following these two steps, I confirmed I had no certificates/keys/anything in Keychain access matching iPhone.  In organizer, nothing is listed under Library -> Provisioning Profiles, nor is anything listed under Devices -> -My Device- -> Provisioning Profiles.
- I also visited the iOS Provisioning Portal & removed the certificates distribution profiles.  Afterwards, there is nothing listed under "Development", not anything under "Distribution."
- I selected Library -> Provisioning Profiles & from the menu Editor -> Refresh from Developer Portal I'm prompted for my login.  I do & the process begins.

Things here seem to diverge from the guide:

- I now have a 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: myID' in Organizer -> Library -> Provisioning Profiles, **however the status of the newly generated profile is "Valid signing identity not found".**

> The first time refresh is pressed, a prompt appears requesting your
>   team member credentials. It is important to answer positively when
>   asked to create your signing certificates if they are needed. To do
>   that, click "Submit Request" when you are prompted and Xcode will
>   create, download and install the certificate(s).

- I am prompted for my credentials, **but I never see the "Submit Request" prompt.**
- When I attempt to build a completely new Hello World app (i.e., single view, a label with static text), it runs in the simulator but refuses to on the app due to **"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains"**

Comment: What is the current state of your keychain?  Do you have the development certificate installed **with** the key that was used to create it?  That is the key (pun unintended) to installing.  If you only have the certificate, then that is worth nothing because you can only use it to verify that *someone else* signed it.  You need the key to sign it.  If you don't have the key you will either have to find the key (export from another machine) or start your certificate creation again (and inform your other team members that they need to all update their profiles and certificates)

Comment: I'm okay re-creating the certificate (that's what I thought I was doing in step 1), but maybe not?  I think you're right, I don't have the private key, as I believe I killed it trying to get to a virgin state.  (I'm a hobbyist, so no worries about other team members.)

Comment: In a correct setup, the certificate will show up with an expansion arrow on the left, and when you expand the entry it will show the private key as a sub-item.  If you don't see this view then you messed up and have to start again from the certificate request.

Comment: Ah, one of them is missing.  How do I blow those away & recreate them?

Comment: Follow the first steps in the provisioning guide (the part where you generate a certificate request and upload it to the developer portal)

Comment: Grah!  I had deleted my provisioning profiles, but never the *certificates*!  That was the part I was missing.  Thanks for working through this with me.  If you want to answer as an answer, I'll upvote & accept so you get proper credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as pointed out in the comment exchange, it seems you deleted your profiles, but not your non-working certificates.  Rule of thumb:  If your certificate doesn't show up with a private key attached to it in your keychain **you cannot use it to sign things**.  If this has happened to you, you either need to

a) Find the computer that has the private key and export it from there.

b) Recreate the certificate from scratch and recreate all your profiles to use it (and then inform your team accordingly because their profiles will suddenly become invalid).